# Behaviour of environment variables in HKCU\Volatile Environment reg key

Tags: scripting, windows-registry, environment-variables, batch, service-accounts

I have a .bat script that runs for every user at login (copies Oracle Java Exception Sites).  It copies a file to:

```
%userprofile%\appdata\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites
```

Unfortunately, it works a little too well.  Sometimes it attempts to run as LocalSystem or other system accounts.

Ok, so let's run this only when domain users are logged in.  I searched for ways to do conditional checks before I copy the file, but I found someone hinting that %userdomain% gets set for the system accounts as well.  From what I understand, this means when SIDs such as S-1-5-18 (LocalSystem), S-1-5-19 (Local Service), and S-1-5-20 (Network Service) are running they become HKCU and therefore may (?) get all of the variables you would see in a **HKCU\Volatile Environment** registry key, namely environment variables such as

```
APPDATA
HOMEDRIVE
HOMEPATH
LOCALAPPDATA
LOGONSERVER
USERDNSDOMAIN
USERDOMAIN
USERNAME
USERPROFILE
```

This means checking %USERDOMAIN% would be pointless because the system accounts inherit these values too.  However, I have not found any official documentation (on MSDN or otherwise) that confirms whether *system* accounts would inherit some or all things a "normal" account would inherit.

So now I have the original problem, but am also curious in depth about Volatile Environment and whether it can actually be used to resolve the problem or not.

1. Is there an obvious way to check for real domain users that I'm overlooking?  Including real (user) local accounts would be ok as well, but not necessary.
2. Do system accounts actually inherit all the variables I would see in Volatile Environment for other users?
3. Bonus question: Where do the Volatile Environment variables get generated from?

Comment: I cannot answer about volatile environment. I can suggest to copy the file only if the user isn't into the Administrators group (otherwise policies are useless...).